# How to extract lower and upper bound in numeric format from a confidence interval string?

Tags: r

Suppose a vector including some confidence intervals as below

```
confint <- c("[0.741 ; 2.233]", "[263.917 ; 402.154]", "[12.788 ; 17.975]", "[0.680 ; 2.450]", "[0.650 ; 1.827]", "[0.719 ; 2.190]")
```

I want to have two new vectors one including the lower Limits in numeric format as

```
lower <- c(0.741, 263.917, 12.788, 0.680, 0.650 , 0.719)
```

and othe including the upper Limits in numeric format like

```
upper <- c(2.233, 402.154, 17.975, 2.450, 1.827, 2.190)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A base R solution

```
lower =  as.numeric(sub(".*?(\\d+\\.\\d+).*", "\\1", confint))
upper =  as.numeric(sub(".*\\b(\\d+\\.\\d+).*", "\\1", confint))

lower
[1]   0.741 263.917  12.788   0.680   0.650   0.719
upper
[1] 2.233 402.154  17.975   2.450   1.827   2.190
```

Answer (score 3):

```
mypattern <- '\\[(\\d+\\.\\d+) ; (\\d+\\.\\d+)\\]'
as.numeric(gsub(mypattern, '\\1', confint))
as.numeric(gsub(mypattern, '\\2', confint))
```

Answer (score 2):

A different `base R` possibility could be:

```
sapply(strsplit(confint, " ; ", fixed = TRUE), function(x) gsub("[^0-9.-]+", "\\1", x) [1])
sapply(strsplit(confint, " ; ", fixed = TRUE), function(x) gsub("[^0-9.-]+", "\\1", x) [2])

[1] "0.741"   "263.917" "12.788"  "0.680"   "0.650"   "0.719"  
[1] "2.233"   "402.154" "17.975"  "2.450"   "1.827"   "2.190"
```

If you need it as a numeric vector:

```
sapply(strsplit(confint, " ; ", fixed = TRUE), function(x) as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.-]+", "\\1", x)) [1])
sapply(strsplit(confint, " ; ", fixed = TRUE), function(x) as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.-]+", "\\1", x)) [2])
```

Comment: @Ronak Shah I updated my post according some of your ideas. Thank you :)

Comment: I realised it needed some more tweaking to get exact output but I think it was a similar approach. +1 to you.

Answer (score 2):

Meanwhile, I came up with another `base R` solution

```
lower <- as.numeric(sub(".]*", "", sub(";.*", "", confint)))
upper <- as.numeric(sub("].*", "", sub(".*;", "", confint)))
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

You can use functions from the **stringr** library.

You can split strings with `str_split()` according a specific character (`;` in your case), then remove character with `str_remove()` (`[` and `]` in your case) and you will obtain what you want.

```
str_remove(str_split_fixed(confint, ";", n = 2)[,1], '\\[') %>% as.numeric()
# [1]   0.741 263.917  12.788   0.680   0.650   0.719
```

Answer (score 1):

A `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df = data.frame(confint)
df = df %>% 
  mutate(confint = gsub("(\\[|\\])","",confint)) %>% 
    separate(confint,c("lower","upper"),";",convert=T)
```